Bonding of urethane layers towards curing with respect to moisture and intentional abrasion of curing surface for adhesion
Here are three follow-up questions to my previous urethane-for-fine-art-painting question under
How do upper layers of urethane adhere or bond to lower layers after curing?

The curing time for the type of urethane I use for fine art painting is 48 hours. (I believe humidity affects the curing time also.) If, however, the surface is dry to the touch before that curing time, aside from electrostatically, how could the new and old layers bond -- or might there be un-felt moisture at play which facilitates the bonding process after the surface is dry to the touch?

Am I correct in assuming even a superfine polishing sandpaper would be sufficient to rough up a surface to promote bonding because that grit would be larger than the to-be-polymerized molecules? If superfine polishing sandpaper actually makes the surface smoother would that still be considered bumpy and inter-lockable in molecular terms?

Might the roughing-up of the surface with sandpaper in anyway change the homogeneity of the molecular polymerized structure; If not, how might roughing up with sandpaper promote bonding at the molecular level?



At this point, you'd need to test to see if your procedures meet your needs. Different grades of sandpaper, curing time, environmental conditions, etc. would all affect adhesion, and the environment in which the art is kept would also influence the chance of delamination.

Thank you. I will try a smoother sandpaper in between layers; thus far I've used relatively coarse sandpaper, but the finer sandpaper will likely produce less visible scratches. The urethane seems to have a remarkable hardness and durability generally, which is good.

BTW, urethanes I've used yellow greatly with age. Not sure about he product you're using.

Thanks. I haven't noticed any yellowing. I've been using a flat-finish urethane now for about 5 or 10 years. The paintings usually are indoors away from stark sunlight. I know linseed oil in particular yellows considerably through the years.
